# Why is this Magento 2 CMS Page Design update is not working?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have a static block for a banner to go across the entire page however I cannot add it with the `CMS Page -> Design` content.

I am using:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="homeslider_1">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">homeslider_1</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

The block I am trying to add is `homeslider_1`. It is not showing up.

If I add it in the cms content part with:

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="homeslider_1"}}
```

it works but now has margin either side.

I am using Magento 2.1.0 with Nginx on Varnish Cache PHP 7.0.

Comment: Just needed to clear the cache